# Does Android Webview timeout iframe objects?

Tags: android, html, iframe, android-webview

I have an app with a webpage called Avebury.html, and this has some javascript created by a colleague which loads a second HTML file inside it called widget. This has an iframe containing an embedded google map. Both are in the assets folder.

The problem is when trying to load Avebury.html in a webview it times out, and points to not being able to find the widget, when the link is correct.

I have tested linking straight to the widget and opening it in the webview, and it loads as it should. Both pages also work correctly in our iOS app and internet explorer.

The widget does take time to load, and I was wondering if the android webview is timing out the widget too soon, and if so is there a way to make it more lenient?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that android webview does not seam to like loading another HTML file from within the app in an iFrame. Removing the unneeded javascript and putting the iframe straight into the page bypassed the problem.